# Delete jobs from at queue on startup

Tags: ubuntu, cron, at, runlevel

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS and I have a cronjob that schedules automatic shutdown commands to a specific `at` queue every minute:

```
$ crontab -e
*/1 * * * * [ -z "$(w -h)" ] && echo "/sbin/shutdown -h now" | at -q w "now + 1 hour"
```

I now have the problem, that when a machine is stopped by hand between now and +1 hour (meaning there is a job scheduled for execution), and the machine is rebooted the next day, it immediately shuts down again.

It seems that overdue `at` jobs are executed when the system starts again. Of course this is very annoying, so I thought, I should delete those jobs when the machine starts again.

I created a script that removes all jobs from the queue in `/usr/sbin/remove_shutdown_jobs`:

```
#!/bin/bash
jobs=$(atq -q w | cut -f1); if [ -n "$jobs" ]; then atrm $jobs; fi;
```

And I made it exectuable:

```
$ ls -lah /usr/sbin/remove_shutdown_jobs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 81 Aug 22 12:06 /usr/sbin/remove_shutdown_jobs
```

I then tried to link it to the `rc5.d` directory and gave it the name `S00` so that it is executed **BEFORE** `atd` is started (my guess is, that I have to remove the jobs before the at daemon is started, otherwise it could pick up those old jobs and execute them):

```
$ ln -s /usr/sbin/remove_shutdown_jobs /etc/rc5.d/S00remove_shutdown_jobs
$ ln -lah
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   30 Aug 31 13:49 S00remove_shutdown_jobs -> /usr/sbin/remove_shutdown_jobs
...
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   13 Jun 16 17:21 S01atd -> ../init.d/atd
...
```

But it seems, that the script is never executed. I tried it with a simple echo script that appends some text to file, and this is also not executed. I thought `rc5.d` is the right directory, because of

```
$ runlevel
N 5
```

I also tried to link it into `rc4.d`, `rc3.d` and `rc2.d` with no luck. I didn't link it to `rc1.d` because this is only for some kind of rescue system and there where only `K01` files in there (kill?), right?

Any idea what I'm missing, or what I've done wrong?

Comment: now I'm wondering why `at` lets you put things into a queue but `atrm` does not let you delete by a queue

Comment: yeah, that bothered me too, but the workaround is kinda okay for me

Answer (score 1):

After reading between the lines, I'm getting the impression that you have an
X-Y problem here.

If I understand your intent correctly, Problem X is, "After my system has
been up for one hour, I want it to automatically halt after the last user
logs out."

Due to the solution you chose for problem X, you now have problem Y which is,
"Whenever I boot up, my `at` queue is full of junk from my system's previous
uptime."

I'm going to propose that you eliminate Problem Y by using a cleaner solution
to Problem X.

Create a small script that checks whether anyone is logged in, and if so,
delays 60 seconds before checking again.  Once no one is logged in, halt the system.

```
# cat << EOF > /root/bin/check-for-halt.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# If anyone is logged in, wait sixty seconds, then check again.
while [ -n "$(w -h)" ] && sleep 60
do
        :
done

# If no one is logged in, halt the system.
[ -z "$(w -h)" ] && /sbin/shutdown -h now
EOF
# chmod 700 /root/bin/check-for-halt.sh
```

Then replace your `crontab` line with this one:

```
@reboot               root    sleep 3600 && /root/bin/check-for-halt.sh
```

You can adjust the `sleep 60` and `sleep 3600` values to suit your needs.  This method eliminates the need to blow away your `at` queue on every reboot.

Answer (score 0):

To run init script you need to add some preamble like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

This will give to init subsystem information on which runlevel to run the script. Also you need to provide kind of info how to stop, how to start, etc.

and record in `cron` like

```
*/1 * * * * ...
```

will run, but it is contra intuitive. The clear way is:

```
* * * * * ...
```

Comment: Depending on the system, you should be able to boot from a Live DVD, or into Recovery Mode, or to a Root console. None of those should start crond.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried adding those comments but unfortunately it didn't work. The script still doesn't run when I boot the machine. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you add the script in `/etc/rc.d` ? Did you exec `chkconfig enable .....`